# What is best way to design E-commerce Product Schema for MongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, nosql, e-commerce

**I want to make the product collection in such a way that it should cover my customized pricing with different varients**

I'm using **expressJs** as a backend and **MongoDB** as database

For Example: Let's say the example of a product Mobile, say 'M'
the different variants with price is as follows

```
 RAM SIZE 4GB, ROM 64 COLOR PINK AMOUNT 1000
 RAM SIZE 4GB, ROM 64 COLOR GOLD AMOUNT 1200
 RAM SIZE 4GB, ROM 128 COLOR GOLD AMOUNT 1700
 RAM SIZE 6GB, ROM 128 COLOR GOLD AMOUNT 2000
......
```

I've used the variant relations like this

```
base_price:500
varient:[{
 ram_size: 4GB
rom_size: 64GB
color:Pink
price:+500
},
{
 ram_size: 6GB
rom_size: 128GB
color:Gold
price:+1500
}]
```

like this.

but, this solution came up with more permutations and combinations

I need an optimal solution for the same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into creational design patterns? On the surface, this seems like the kind of scenario that would suit the [Abstract Factory](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/abstract-factory) or [Decorator](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator) pattern.